# Why is else clause being evaluated first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I don't understand why is the **else** clause from function **find_by_year()** being evaluated first. Please find my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def list(movie_list):
    if len(movie_list) == 0:
        print("There are no movies in the list.\n")
        return
    else:
        for i, movie in enumerate(movie_list, start=1):
            print(f"{i}. {movie[0]} ({movie[1]}) @ {movie[2]}")
        print()

def add(movie_list):
    name = input("Name: ")
    year = input("Year: ")
    price = input("Price: ")
    movie = [name, year, price]
    movie_list.append(movie)
    print(f"{movie[0]} was added.\n")
    
def delete(movie_list):
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if number < 1 or number > len(movie_list):
        print("Invalid movie number.\n")
    elif len(movie_list) == 0:
        print("List is empty")
    else:
        movie = movie_list.pop(number-1)
        print(f"{movie[0]} was deleted.\n")

def find_by_year(movie_list):
    year = int(input("Year: "))
    for movie in movie_list:
        if movie[1] == year:
            print(movie[0], " was released in ", movie[1])
            return
        else:
            print("Invalid year")
    print()

def display_menu():
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("list - List all movies")
    print("add -  Add a movie")
    print("del -  Delete a movie")
    print("find - Find a movie")
    print("exit - Exit program")
    print()
    
def main():
    movie_list = [["Monty Python and the Holy Grail", 1975, 9.95],
                  ["On the Waterfront", 1954, 5.59],
                  ["Cat on a Hot Tin Roof", 1958, 7.95 ]]
    
    display_menu()
    
    while True:        
        command = input("Command: ")
        if command.lower() == "list":
            list(movie_list)
        elif command.lower() == "add":
            add(movie_list)
        elif command.lower() == "del":
            delete(movie_list)
        elif command.lower() == "find":
            find_by_year(movie_list)
        elif command.lower() == "exit":
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid command. Please try again.\n")
    print("Bye!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Actual output:**

```
COMMAND MENU
list - List all movies
add -  Add a movie
del -  Delete a movie
find - Find a movie
exit - Exit program

Command: find
Year: 1954
Invalid year
On the Waterfront  was released in  1954
```

Before I added the return statement, **find()** was giving the below output:

```
COMMAND MENU
list - List all movies
add -  Add a movie
del -  Delete a movie
find - Find a movie
exit - Exit program

Command: find
Year: 1954
Invalid year
On the Waterfront  was released in  1954
Invalid year
```

Since the **else** clause was being executed first, I added **return** statement under the **if** clause but once I added return, for loop didn't iterate the third time.

Please help me understand where I went wrong.

Comment: _why is the else clause from function find()_ - well, there is no function `find()` in your snippet.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as name of your function, it's a built-in and you shadow it

Comment: I modified my question, couldn't do it in second half. The function is find_by_year()

Comment: @guy If you see, I have typecasted the variable "year" and the value in the list is also int. If it were data type issue, why would it evaluate the second time? It should have thrown an error.

Comment: There's no `int` in the `add` function, perhaps your years are stored as string?

Comment: For the first movie in your list, the year is not equal to 1954, so the condition is false. Move the failure message to *after* the loop.

Comment: Just a tip really, `break` rather than `return` would stop the loop. Also check `continue`

Comment: "the else clause was being executed first" - **that means the `if` condition was not met**. Right? So. In your own words, where the code says `if movie[1] == year:`, why should this condition be met for the newly added movies? Hint: look at the code that adds movies to the list. Look at how it chooses the `year` value for those: `year = input("Year: ")`. Notice a difference between that and, for example, the code in `find_by_year` that asks for a year to search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop through the list, and printing out a response to every movie you iterate over. The first entry in `movie_list` isn't from 1954, which prints the `Invalid year`.

An easy way to fix it is to simply remove the else statement, and move the content of it outside of the loop, so it only prints the message if no movie in the list matches the input.

```
def find_by_year(movie_list):
    year = int(input("Year: "))
    for movie in movie_list:
        if movie[1] == year:
            print(movie[0], " was released in ", movie[1])
            return
    print("Invalid year.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your function will run for every movie in the list.

The first item in your list is `["Monty Python and the Holy Grail", 1975, 9.95]`. It is going to check the condition `movie[1] == year` for it. As `movie[1]` for this item is not the one you inputed, the result will be `False`. As the result is `False`, it will run to the `else` block, which contains `print("Invalid year")`.

Then, it will iterate to the second item, which will have the condition resulting `True` and will print the movie information.

Answer (score 0):

The for loops' is what is printing the invalid year

```py
def find_by_year(movie_list):
    year = int(input("Year: "))
    for movie in movie_list:
        if movie[1] == year:
            print(movie[0], " was released in ", movie[1])
            return
        else:
            print("Invalid year")
```

If the first movie does not match the year, the else statement is called.

In the output that you gave, it looks like the second movie was the one that corresponded to the year, thus, in the first iteration, the `else` block was ran.

You can solve this in mulitiple ways

```py
# Not recommended
 for movie in movie_list:
    if movie[1] == year:
        print(movie[0], " was released in ", movie[1])
        return
 else:
     print("Invalid year")
```

The else block will only run if the for loop runs successfully. This means that only if none of the movies are in that year, the return function will not be called, meaning the else block will run

The better way to write this code will be

```py
 for movie in movie_list:
        if movie[1] == year:
            print(movie[0], " was released in ", movie[1])
            return
        
 print("Invalid year")
```

This achieves the same thing, but does not use the confusing for-else loop.

*Also, don't use the word list as a function name, it's a built-in method.